# React native this.props.screenProps.mapLoc.markers.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-maps

I have following issue, cannot wrap my head around. I am following react-native-maps example and trying to set up markers. However .map() keeps popping an error:

> this.props.screenProps.mapLoc.markers.map is not a function

The code is:

```
        <MapView
          style={{ left:0, right: 0, top:0, bottom: 0, position: 'absolute', backgroundColor: '#fff' }}
          region={this.state.region}
          onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange.bind(this)}
        >
          {this.props.screenProps.mapLoc.markers.map(marker => (
            <MapView.Marker
              coordinate={marker.Coords}
              title={marker.Name}
              description={marker.Description}
            />
          ))}
        </MapView>
```

Data is params is there and as should:

> {"screenProps":{"cats":[],"mapLoc":{"markers":{"Name":"Blank","Description":"Blank","Coords":{"latitude":56.947902,"longitude":24.097722}}}},"navigation":{"state":{"key":"Map","routeName":"Map"}}}

no clue what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Objects do not have a function `map()`, [only arrays do](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

`this.props.screenProps.mapLoc.markers` is an object.